# How do I update a formula with Homebrew?

Tags: homebrew

How do I update a formula?

I ran `brew update`. However, `mongodb` is still outdated according to `brew outdated`:

```
mongodb (1.4.3-x86_64 < 1.6.5-x86_64)
```

Answer (score 463, accepted):

First, [`update`](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage#update-options) brew's internal list of formulae to the latest:

```
brew update
```

To upgrade only the `mongodb` formula, use [`install`](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage#install-options-formulacask-):

```
brew install mongodb
```

To [`upgrade`](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage#upgrade-options-outdated_formulaoutdated_cask-) all outdated formulae:

```
brew upgrade
```

Comment: When I run "brew upgrade <packagename>", it actually upgrade all outdated packages, taking hours instead of seconds. That is a very bad design. The correct way to "JUST upgrade one single package" is "brew install <packagename>", which is again a confusing design.

Comment: I also just ran "brew upgrade <packagename> <packagename>" (I wanted to update a package and a direct dependency), and it also then sat upgrading ALL packages instead of these two.

Comment: In fact "brew install <packagename>" doesn't really update the package, instead it only says the package is already installed.  Maybe this answer is too old, but now you have to run "brew install -f <packagename>"

Comment: With Homebrew 4.1.22 at least, if you get message that package is already installed, you can update a single package with `brew reinstall <packagename>`

Answer (score 82):

You can update all outdated packages like so:

```
brew install `brew outdated`
```

or

```
brew outdated | xargs brew install
```

or

```
brew upgrade
```

This is from the brew site..

for upgrading individual formula:

```
brew install formula-name && brew cleanup formula-name
```

Comment: I think can now just type `brew upgrade outdated` and skip all the complex crap.

Comment: It is 2021 now. And no, you can't. `brew upgrade outdate` will update ALL outdated formulas.

Answer (score 44):

You will first need to update the local formulas by doing

```
brew update
```

and then upgrade the package by doing

```
brew upgrade formula-name
```

An example would be if i wanted to upgrade **mongodb**, i would do something like this, assuming **mongodb** was already installed :

```
brew update && brew upgrade mongodb && brew cleanup mongodb
```

Answer (score 16):

Well, I just did

```
brew install mongodb
```

and followed the instructions that were output to the `STDOUT` after it finished installing, and that seems to have worked just fine. I guess it kinda works just like `make install` and overwrites (upgrades) a previous install.

Comment: Brew installs mongodb into `$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/Cellar/mongodb/<version>/`, so you most likely have both versions installed. It then symlinks the latest version into `$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/bin`, etc. Running `brew cleanup mongodb` will delete the old version.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use brew install to upgrade an installed formula. If you want upgrade all of outdated formulas, you can use the command below.

```
brew outdated | xargs brew upgrade
```

Comment: You better explain your solution, to be helpful to the other SO users. Posting just code is not a best practice here.

Comment: how is this different from part of @user689741's answer above?

Answer (score -1):

I prefer to upgrade all **homebrew formulae** and **homebrew cask formulae**.

I added a Bourne shell function to my environment for this one (I load a .bashrc)

```
function updatebrew() {
set -x;
brew update;
brew cleanup;
brew cask upgrade --greedy
)
}
```

- `set -x` for transparency: So that the terminal outputs whatever Homebrew is doing in the background.
- `brew update` to update homebrew formulas
- `brew cleanup` to remove any change left over after installations
- `brew cask upgrade --greedy` will install all casks; both those with versioning information and those without

Comment: I can't recommend this if you have installed postgres with extensions from homebrew. I there has been a new postgres release, it will just replace the old one with the new one, leaving you with no simple way to upgrade your database with it.

Comment: @narrowtux That‘s always the case with database upgrades. You need to handle backups and restores. It‘s therefore best to exclude them (blacklist). I considered that outside the scope of this question.